# Validating form OOP

Tags: php, html, oop

I am having trouble making sure all of my form inputs are filled in OOP. Normally I would have been able to do this. But I am kind of new in programming with OOP. I want to make sure that when my button is clicked on.

It will control if all of my forms are empty or not. If empty, it has to echo a message (the message is in dutch but it basically means you still have unfilled inputs). However, it does not work. The message is just always shown, Even when I do fill in my inputs and click on submit. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
<?php

  class UserForm{

//Making properties to later use
private $Vvoornaam;
private $Vachternaam;
private $Vemail;
private $Vbericht;
private $Bsubmit;
public function __contruct() {

//Giving the properties a value

$this->Vvoornaam = $_POST["voornaam"];
$this->Vachternaam = $_POST["achternaam"];
$this->Vemail = $_POST["email"];
$this->$Vbericht = $_POST["bericht"];
$this->$Bsubmit = $_POST["submit"];
}

public function Index() {

//Checking if a message has been posted yes or no. If yes, then execute the code from line 21 to 41

if(isset($_POST[$this->Bsubmit]) && empty($this->Vvoornaam) || empty($this->Vachternaam) || empty($this->Vemail) || empty($this->Vbericht)) {
    echo "U moet nog al uw gegevens invullen";
  }
}
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { 

   $userForm = new UserForm(); $userForm->Index();
```

}

```
?>
```

The problem as you can see, is that this message is supposed to come when you submit and the inputs are empty. Yet, this message is always there.

[image]
I hope you guys can help me out. That would be great!

[Newest notice after putting a s in my construct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrbdS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrbdS.png)

Comment: Instead of making a "validation form" you should be using [domain object](http://wiki.c2.com/?DomainObject) approach. Make a `User` domain object, with validation rules in the setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `s` in `__contruct()`, you could update that to:

```
public function __construct()
```

Also, I think this will be empty `empty($this->Vbericht)`

Try removing the leading dollar sign from `$this->$`

Change

```
$this->$Vbericht = $_POST["bericht"];
$this->$Bsubmit = $_POST["submit"];
```

to

```
$this->Vbericht = $_POST["bericht"];
$this->Bsubmit = $_POST["submit"];
```

Your function would look like:

```
public function Index() {
    if (isset($this->Bsubmit) && empty($this->Vvoornaam) || empty($this->Vachternaam) || empty($this->Vemail) || empty($this->Vbericht)) {
        echo "U moet nog al uw gegevens invullen";
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I did not see that mistake, it, unfortunately, does not solve my problem. Check the new edit

Comment: hi! Hahaha, I did not see that I forgot a s in my construct. It helps a lot. I know have two notices. It is a step, yet my problem is not solved. If you are willing to still help me out it would be great. Check my new edit for update!

Comment: So right now, the setup of your code looks something like this right? https://3v4l.org/T1cGV

Comment: yes, exactly. You can see the newest screenshot of the form. The notices are gone. But the message "inputs are empty" does not pop up when I click the button.

Comment: yes exactly, I have the exact same code. May I ask why on line 16 until 20 you have taken the $_POST away?

Comment: Just checking, did you add `method="POST"` to your form tag? And are you making sure to check if it is a POST?

Comment: I do have method="POST" in my form tag. I also have an action. I used to have a $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]="post" in my if statement. But I deleted it

Comment: I think you should check for that. For example:  `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $userForm = new UserForm();
    $userForm->Index();
}`

Comment: I have done it in a different if statement. I does not make any changes. Should I just put it in the same if statement as in my isset?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I just had to add the $_POST to the variables! It works now. Bedankt!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this using **if statement**

```
if($this->Vvoornaam =='' || $this->Vachternaam=='' || $this->Vemail=='' || $this->$Vbericht==''){
echo "All field must be filled.";
exit();
}else{
echo "everything is filled";
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your time to answer my question! I have used the code you have given me. But the only problem is that the message "all fields must be filled". Does not go away even when I click on the submit button and they filled. The message does not switch to "Everything is filled". I don't know how to make sure the message changes whenever I fill in the form.

Comment: what are you using at the front end. is it ajax/jquery or angularjs etc.

Answer (score -1):

Also make sure you set your properties values after you checked whenever the values from the `$_POST` array are empty or not set.

I would make a function like this

```
public function ValidateForm($data) {

    if(!isset($data["voornaam"]) && strlen($data["voornaam"]) < 1) {
      echo "Please fill in the 'voornaam' field";
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $this->SetData($data);
      return true;
    }
```

so now we made sure once all the inputs are set, we can call our function:

```
public function SetData($data) {
  $this->voornaam = $data["voornaam"];
}
```

and your input name would be like this

```
name="data[voornaam]"
```

In your html/php file, the function will be triggered once the submit has been set.

```
$obj = new UserForm();
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) { $obj->ValidateForm($_POST["data"]); }
```

Comment: @Progrock oops, it should've been strlen

Comment: `isset($data["voornaam"]` trailing bracket missing. `strlen($data["voornaam")`, invalid syntax.  Do test your code.